# Call googleapis from java code using proxy

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, proxy, google-api

I'm using below code to call GoogleAPIs from java code

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
        .fromStream(ChatBotResourceAPIAI.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("onboarding-audience-chatbot.json"))
            .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
```

but now I have to use proxy as a middle layer.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.212.83.121", 8080));
```

How can I merge both of above to make sure the googleapis are called using proxy?

Comment: It's not duplicate. The referenced question is 4 years old and is different then above code.

Comment: These libraries have not changed in eight years, four year old code should work just fine.